# Encode in Java and Decode in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I want to pass a Base64 Image to the front end in a parameter.

I tried to send normal Base64 but it was giving me an error, probably because of the special characters in the Base64 Image.

So I tried in Java:

```
String base64Signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image); // Encode to base64
return URLEncoder.encode(base64Signature, "utf-8"); // This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIMEformat
```

And in Javascript `data.Signature` has the image data. Neither

```
 vm.Signature = data.Signature;
```

or

```
 vm.Signature = decodeURIComponent(data.Signature);
```

worked. I copied the image data String in a online converter and it didn't display anything.

How should I do this?

Comment: Any ideas?? I need help

Comment: Try using `decodeURI` instead of  `decodeURIComponent` in javascript side

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that Java's `URLEncoder` encodes spaces as `+` signs and JavaScript's decoder expects spaces as `%20`s. You can try replacing the `+` signs, for example:

`decodeURIComponent(data.Signature.replace(/\+/g, '%20'));`